# use javascript in a commandAction to open a new link

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, javascript, ribbon

I would like on a `CommandAction=""` to open a page.
I successfully done it with the following code:

```
<CommandUIHandler
  Command="CustomTab.MyButton1" 
  CommandAction="{SiteUrl}/Lists/Test" />
```

I would like to do for an another `CommandAction` 
I got the good link with :

```
_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + '/' + Lists/MyLibrary
```

but when I try to insert it inside my `CommandAction` nothing happen.

```
    <CommandUIHandler
      Command="CustomTab.MyButton2" 
      CommandAction="javascript:_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + '/' + Lists/MyLibrary 
/>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you what the site collection URL with `siteAbsoluteUrl`.

You can use this token to get it : `{SiteCollection}`

```
 <CommandUIHandler
      Command="CustomTab.MyButton2" 
      CommandAction="{SiteCollection}/Lists/ListUrl"/>
```

URLs and tokens in SP2013 : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms431831.aspx